# Is it possible to load a PyQT UIC file from a zip

Tags: python, pyqt, zip

I'd like to be able to distribute some UIC files along with other resources for a python script bundled into a zip file.  I've been unable to find a method of loading the UIC files directly from a zip - I could of course unzip them into a temp directory or somesuch, but things would be neater and more self-contained if that were not needed. Has anybody got a trick for this? [Google is not my friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=pyqt%20UIC%20zip&oq=pyqt%20UIC%20zip&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.3682j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=pyqt%20UIC%20%2bzip&oq=pyqt%20UIC%20%2bzip&gs_l=serp.3...194725.195347.0.195674.5.4.1.0.0.1.111.267.3j1.4.0...0.0.0..1c.1.15.psy-ab.FSH-Olt3-hk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.cGE&fp=779a49d6fdd15bbe&biw=1264&bih=1471) on this one:

Answer (score 0):

I recommend pyinstaller ... it allows you to not only compile the python file into an exe, but it also allows you to package extras.  You have 2 choices for compilation.

1. one-directory
2. one-file

The one-file creates a stand alone exe and the one-directory builds the exe with a directory of components.

I use qtdesigner to create a qrc resource file which contains resources my ui needs and pyinstaller to build my distributable exe.  I like to use autohotkey to create an installer for my python apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder you are looking for a virtual(or wrapped) filesystem layer that encapsulates underlying physical storage system, ex zip? If that makes sense to your task, try [pyfilesystem](http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/).

Ex,

```
from fs.zipfs import ZipFS
projects_fs = ZipFS('source.zip')
uic = projects_fs.open('uic/ooxx.uic')
```